# Powershell CM2012 import Application with XML

Tags: xml, powershell, sccm

I have created a powershell script to import applications to CM2012 based on input in a XML file example I found. 
Does anybody know where I can an example of the XML import file that is complete with all settings/parameters?

The file looks like this:

```
<Applications>
<Application>
<Name>Powershell Import</Name>
<Description>Import with Powershell</Description>
<Manufacturer> Johan Powershell</Manufacturer>
<SoftwareVersion>3</SoftwareVersion>
<AutoInstall>false</AutoInstall>
<DeploymentTypes>
<DeploymentType>
<MsiInstaller>true</MsiInstaller>
<InstallationFileLocation>\\test</InstallationFileLocation>
</DeploymentType>
<DeploymentType>
<ScriptInstaller>true</ScriptInstaller>
<DeploymentTypeName>Install Thinkiosk</DeploymentTypeName>
<InstallationProgram>msiexec /i \\corp\users\udc\a920268\Program\Quest_ActiveRolesManagementShellforActiveDirectoryx64_151.msi /qn</InstallationProgram>
<InstallationBehaviorType>InstallForSystem</InstallationBehaviorType>   <!-- InstallForSystem; InstallForUser; InstallForSystemIfResourceIsDeviceOtherwiseInstallForUser -->
<ContentLocation>\\test</ContentLocation>
<LogonRequirementType>WhereOrNotUserLoggedOn</LogonRequirementType>     <!-- OnlyWhenNoUserLoggedOn; OnlyWhenUserLoggedOn; WhereOrNotUserLoggedOn -->
</DeploymentType>
</DeploymentTypes>
</Application>
</Applications>
```

Say for example I want to change Language I have no idea what it should be named in the XML file or under which category?

Answer (score 0):

I've just started playing around with SCCM2012 objects.

Can't you check another application and see how the fields are named?

In below  example I've used the application with LocalizedDisplayName "Google Chrome"

```
$DeploymentTypes = Get-CMDeploymentType -ApplicationName "Google Chrome"
$SDMPackageXML = $DeploymentTypes | Select SDMPackageXML -ExpandProperty SDMPackageXML
```

You can deserialize the xml to an object like this:

```
$DTInfo = [Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer]::DeserializeFromString($SDMPackageXML)
```

You can than drill down into "DeploymentTypes"

```
$DTInstances = $DTInfo.DeploymentTypes
```

And from there you can drill down into for instance "Installer"

```
$DTInstance = $DTInstances[0]
$DTInstaller = $DTInstance | Select Installer -ExpandProperty Installer
```

Hope this can help. Good luck with your script.

Grts.

Comment: Ahhh that just made my day but I have another question about the Add-CMDeployment cmdlet, how do I add a Uninstall command? The cmdlet autogenerates this for me and I dont want that cause I need logging for uninstallation. 
And maybe how to set the default Language with either New-CMApplication or Set-CMApplication??